# Alert to warn user to click button after a set time

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, timer

What I want to do is (in JavaScript&html):

If after 5 minute of opening the page, the user haven't clicked a particular button on the page, I want the system to display an alert to remind user to click the button. And if the user still haven't clicked the button after the alert, the alert will display again after another 5 minute. But once the user clicked the button, the alert will not show again.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`

Comment: I'm not sure how to clear the timer when button is clicked. Currently I only have: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var timer;
function setTimer() {
timer = setTimeout("alert('You need to click submit!!')", 5000000);
}

Comment: Shows lack of research and no example provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said:

> Currently I only have:  var timer; function setTimer() { timer =
>   setTimeout("alert('You need to click submit!!')", 5000000); }

You just need to `clearInterval()` your timer, if the button has been clicked. If not, it automaticly will show the alert again and again after the given time.

**edit:**
 In this case you alert-function has too look something like this:

```
var timer; 
function setTimer() { 
     timer = setInterval(function()
     {
         alert('You need to click submit!!');
     }, 5000000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You can set a variable action = false
2- setInterval to check variable action after 5 mins to show alert if false
2.1 - If alert showed restart the setInterval for second time
3- catch click event on document to set variable action to true

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    var action = 0;
    checkAction();
    var interval;

    function checkAction()
    {
        interval = setInterval(function()
        {
            if(action == 1)
            {
                action = 2;
                alert("second warning");
            }
            if(action == 0)
            {
                alert("first warning");
                action = 1;
                clearInterval(interval);
                checkAction();
            }
        },5000);
    }

    $('body').click(function()
    {
        action == 2;
    });

});
```

something like this will work for you I think, this checks after 5 secs if a click on the page was done.
`action = 0` --- noclicks
`action = 1` --- noclicks first warning sent
`action = 2` --- user clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` for this. Just mention the time in milliseconds and reset the timer when any key is pressed or mouse is moved. For example:
[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1zjspn5t/)

```
var ideal;
document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

function showmsg() {
  alert("Click on submit button");
}

function resetTimer() {
  clearTimeout(ideal);
  ideal = setTimeout(showmsg, 3000);
}
window.onload = resetTimer;
```

and add an event to your button for clearing theTimeout. Like:

```
  document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
  document.onmousemove = function() {
    return false
  }
  document.onkeypress = function() {
    return false
  }
  clearTimeout(ideal);
}
```